# Need to user-to-user data in the database. How to avoid a disaster?

Tags: php, sql

In my requirements, every user on the website can see a score attached to other users. It gets calculated based of their profile parameters. My score to someone else will be one, but their score to me will be another one.

What I have done so far
Table in the MySQL database like so:

```
___UserID1___|___UserID2___|___Score___|___Last_Uopdated___
   1         |      2      |   45      |   1235686744
   2         |      1      |   24      |   1235645332
```

When  a user views someones page, my score class is checking if the record for this pair exists in the database and if not, calculates it and records it. This works fine, because no one will look at absolutely every user page on the site.

Now I need to pull users and sort them based on score. SO I thought, I can create a cronjob, and run it every night, so it will update scores in the database and create them for every pair of user both ways.

Well, problem is I am planing a system for over 500,000 users and I am worried, it will bring my database down and create huge database. So for 500,000 we are talking about 250 billion records... :/

Does anyone know any other way of creating this feature? May be calculation on the fly... or any other way?

Comment: Why would you NOT calculate it on-the-fly?

Comment: Why is a users score depending on the user that views the users profile? Or can users assign personal points to eachother?

Comment: Q: When user1 logs on, what exactly does he see? 499,999 rows, for his "relative" score to each other user?  Or what?

Comment: You should calculate it on the fly always because you have to do it anyway always .suppose the record(row) is exist for any pair of a user but as you said score is changing according to the parameters on the user profile so you have to update it always so instead of inserting and updating records always it will be better to show them rather then inserting in database and then fetching to display them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was in your situation I would create the calculation on the fly. I would generate the scores using your function and then store the values into the database then. That way whenever any user visits any page, the scores are updated. This is an incremental approach rather than trying to run the function on every single combination possible at once. Plus no more database disaster :)

If you have a page that ranks all the users by score, it would be much simpler if you use pagination and use the ORDER BY and OFFSET, LIMIT features of SQL queries instead of fetching all users at once.